# Is it possible complete AWS authentication in PL SQL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to find if it is possible to complete an AWS authentication in PL SQL so I can complete an API call within APEX.

I have found that UTL_HTTP can be used within PL SQL to complete an API call, I am just not sure if there is a way to complete AWS authentication. Thank you.

Here is my understanding for making an API call:

```
declare
    v_req       utl_http.req;
    v_res       utl_http.resp;
    v_buffer    varchar2(4000); 
    v_body      varchar2(4000) := '{"field":"value"}'; -- Your JSON
begin
    -- Set connection.
    v_req := utl_http.begin_request('http://your.api/operation', 'POST');
    utl_http.set_authentication(v_req, 'your_username','your_password');
    utl_http.set_header(v_req, 'content-type', 'application/json'); 
    utl_http.set_header(v_req, 'Content-Length', length(v_body));
    
    -- Invoke REST API.
    utl_http.write_text(v_req, v_body);
  
    -- Get response.
    v_res := utl_http.get_response(v_req);
    begin
        loop
            utl_http.read_line(v_res, v_buffer);
            -- Do something with buffer.
            dbms_output.put_line(v_buffer);
        end loop;
        utl_http.end_response(v_res);
    exception
        when utl_http.end_of_body then
            utl_http.end_response(v_res);
    end;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: **YOUR** code where you attempt a solution (do not include any access tokens or other personal credentials); the issues/errors with your code; and the expected behaviour.

Comment: @MT0 as mentioned in the question asked I am wondering if its possible. I can't provide much in way of a reproducible example of something I do not know if PL SQL even allows or not.

Comment: Can you expand on exactly what you are trying to accomplish?  AWS authentication generally involves multi-factor authentication (MFA) which would generally require a device.  Programmatic interfaces to those devices are generally not created because they would primarily be used to reduce security-- if the computer can provide the additional factor automatically, you're removed the M from MFA.

Comment: @JustinCave yeah no worries, as an expansion on what I am trying to do: I wanted to try to have APEX run API calls to Amazon. I have the Amazon API working in postman with an AWS Signature and a refresh token in the body. I am wondering if PL SQL would have something to let me perform the AWS Authorization so my APEX can complete the API call. Thank you.

Comment: If you can do something in Postman, you should be able to replicate that by making utl_http calls in PL/SQL.